# How to convert 3D bin packing problem to 2D bin packing approximation?

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, algorithms, heuristics, knapsack

I'm trying to approximately solve a 3D container loading problem. Is it possible to use 2D bin packing algorithms? If so, how do we make the transformation? What are the conditions needed to make the transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the attached file:

In the $m$-dimensional bin packing problem ($m$-BPP) there are many large boxes
of equal sizes, which are called bins, and the objective is to pack all $n$ items into a minimum number of bins.

We can translate any $m$-BPP instance into an instance of $(m+1)$-SPP (strip packing problem), where the additional $(m+1)$st direction (the height of the strip)
is used to count bins.

I hope, [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgxhtjtuk60u1u5/Multidimensional%20Orthogonal%20Packing.pdf?dl=0) link would be useful.